# Facebook like plugin, comment box and send box is pop-ups under layer

Tags: facebook, plugins, popup, z-index, show

I'm facing an issue with the Facebook *like* plugin. Here is the screenshot of the issue:

[image]

As you see in the screenshot, the comment box is popups under the body's parts. How can I arrange it to popup over?

BTW, none of the container parts of the body (divs, tables, etc.) has z-index value bydefault, so I tried to set the z-index value of the container of the plugin but it doesn't work...

Is there a way to arrange it?

Comment: can you link to the page with the like button, so i can browse the source and surrounding css please.

Answer (score 0):

In the docs there is this FAQ:

> When I click the Like button, the popup window (or "flyout") doesn't
>   show. Why?
>
> If the Like button is placed near the edge of an HTML element with the
>   overflow property set to hidden, the flyout may be clipped or
>   completely hidden when the button is clicked. This can be remedied by
>   setting the overflow property to a value other than hidden, such as
>   visible, scroll, or auto.

bottom of the page here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/